# Passing a variable from template.php to a js

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, variables

so in my THEME_preprocess_page I have

```
drupal_add_js(array('variableName' => 'value'), 'setting');
```

and in my js file

```
alert(Drupal.settings.variableName);
```

I get 'undefined' is it possible to pass a variable to javascript in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following

```
$(function() {
    alert(Drupal.settings.variableName);
});
```

Comment: also does not work in my module, works in my main theme template.php

Comment: not sure why it isn't working for you module.. the `$(function() {` makes sure the page is fully loaded, so you won't call the var before it's loaded